# Are there any differences between Jesus's commandments and God's commandments?

Tags: exegesis, life-of-jesus, revelation, commandments

I always read about **Jesus's commandments** as something new in the bible; those commandments changed the way Christians see the Moshe writings.

The bible  commentaries in this page of [Rev 14:12](http://bible.cc/revelation/14-12.htm) don't explain about the **commandments of God**, where saints keep them and have the faith of Jesus, nothing about  Jesus's commandments. So, there are any difference or are the same?

Comment: not really sure what "seers of the Moshe writings" means. In general my understanding though is that Jesus was just elaborating on God's Commandments from the OT; revealing their true meaning.

Comment: TY Thomas, I mean the way christians see the old testament

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Christians believe Jesus is God, and so there is inherently no semantic difference between "Jesus' commandments" and "God's commandments" (with some minority exceptions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doubting Thomas said it well in his comment: *"Jesus was just elaborating on God's Commandments from the OT; revealing their true meaning."*. In that spirit, here's my elaboration.

In [Matthew 5:21-48](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205:21-48&version=NIV1984), there are six *it has been said* statements:

- Do not murder
- Do not commit adultery
- Anyone who divorces his wife must give her a certificate of divorce
- Do not break your oath
- Eye for eye, and tooth for tooth
- Love your neighbor and hate your enemy

In each case, Jesus says a little word, *"but"*, and then goes one huge step further. Just to take the last one as an example:

> You have heard that it was said, ‘Love your neighbor and hate your enemy.’ But I tell you: Love your enemies and pray for those who persecute you, that you may be sons of your Father in heaven. He causes his sun to rise on the evil and the good, and sends rain on the righteous and the unrighteous. If you love those who love you, what reward will you get? Are not even the tax collectors doing that? And if you greet only your brothers, what are you doing more than others? Do not even pagans do that? Be perfect, therefore, as your heavenly Father is perfect.

See [the above verses](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205:21-48&version=NIV1984) or the [full chapter](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+5&version=NIV1984) for more.

Finally, note that Jesus Himself saw no difference. As He mentions just before the above verses:

> Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them. I tell you the truth, until heaven and earth disappear, not the smallest letter, not the least stroke of a pen, will by any means disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished.

[Matthew 5:17-18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205:17-18&version=NIV1984)

Comment: exactly what I was thinking. +1
The "you have heard that it was said" really emphasizes it: the spiritual leaders had taught letter-of-the-law obedience, Christ was revealing the spirit-of-the-law that should have been recognized from the first.

Comment: The link's footnotes backs your answer. The "But" is complementing His teaching. @DoubtingThomas When I read the "you have heard that it was said" it reminds me the oral traditions, that wasn't written by the time.

Answer (score 5):

Jesus said:

> 30 "I and the Father are one.” *John 10:30*

That means that Jesus has same goals, norms and moral values as His Father. 
Jesus had never desire for independence from God.
Jesus is staggeringly connected with His Father.

Jesus also said:

> The works I do in my Father’s name testify about me. John 10:25

So how could be Jesus's and God's commands different if Jesus did in Father's name?

Answer (score 2):

1. Jesus claimed to be one with God the Father.  As he said in John, "If you have seen the Father, you have seen me." He also says, "I and the Father are one." (John 10:30)  One of the core doctrines that holds all Chalcedonian Christians together is the idea of the Trinity - that God exists as a "three-in-one." As Jesus and God are the same person, by definition, they cannot contradict one another
2. In the Sermon on the Mount, Jesus specifically states that he came "not to abolish the law, but to fufill it."  (Matthew 5:17) Indeed the expression, "not one jot nor tittle" stems from the fact that Jesus is saying that he doesn't change the law in even the most insignificant way. (A jot is Y, which in Hebrew looks like an apostrophe.  It's the smallest letter in the Hebrew alphabet.  A title is like an accent mark). As he continues in 5:18, "I tell you the truth, until heaven and earth disappear, not even the smallest detail of God's law will disappear until its purpose is achieved."

   The Sermon continues that we are to be Perfect, "even has your Father in Heaven is perfect". If there is a distinction to be made between the OT law and the NT, it is that Jesus drives home the idea that not only must our actions conform to the words of the law, but our hearts also.  While the "law" only said you can't commit adultery, Jesus says that if you lust after a woman, you've committed adultery in your heart.  As such, Jesus is showing that he is merely applying the same law more fully.
3. When Jesus was asked to summarize the law, he said "Love the Lord your God with all your heart, all your soul, and all your mind. And the second is like unto it - Love your neighbor as yourself."  When he says that all the Law hangs on this, he isn't introducing anything novel. In fact, he is quoting from different parts of Leviticus and Deuteronomy.  Furthermore, he is also referencing the 10 commandments, using a standard formulation called "the two tables."  If one looks at the 10 commandments, the first four show how people are to act before God (No other gods / No images / no other worship/ Sabbath), the second six are how people are to act before other people (parents / no killing /adultery / false witness / stealing / coveting).  Jesus' formulation is nothing but a good shorthand to the "two tables."
4. In John 14:15, Jesus links faith in himself with the "law" established between God the Father in the OT with faith in himself.  The basis of obedience is summed up when he says, "If you love me, keep my commandments."  By his commandments, he is referring to the whole of the law established by God with the Israelites at Sinai.

In Revelation 14:12, John is exhorting Christians to persevere.  He is saying specifically, "Here is a call for the endurance of the saints, those who keep the commandments of God and their faith in Jesus." (ESV).

It is our faith in Jesus, grounded in love, that allows us to keep the commandments that He (as God the Father) commanded.  <sup>Please forgive the modalist heresy there.  The point is to remember that Jesus is God, even though they are distinct.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The difference between Jesus'commandments and God's commandments is that Jesus' commandments are given under a new covenant, one between between the Father and the Son, that Jesus himself fulfilled.  The commandments from Sinai were given to only the Hebrews, and were conditional upon their obedience.

Did Jesus end the law or not? Yes he did. Jesus said "It is finished," that is, the old covenant was fulfilled by his perfect life and death. He is the Lamb of God.

Matthew 5:17 says "Do not think that I came to destroy the Law or the Prophets. **I did not come to destroy but to fulfill**. For assuredly, I say to you, till heaven and earth pass away, one jot or one tittle will by no means pass from the law **till all is fulfilled**"

The biggest difference between Jesus' commandment and God's commandment (I hate to even make the distinction since Jesus is God but for the sake of answering the question I do so) is that not only did Jesus fulfill the OT law and commandments, he also fulfills the NT commandment in us - to love God and our neighbor. The bible makes it very clear that we as fallen people cannot follow any commandment. As born again people, we have the Spirit of Christ.  Christ in us, Christ as us, can love God and love our neighbor. We bring no offering except ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus's Commandments were the same as the Ten Commandments. If you love your neighbor you will not steal from him or covet what is his you will not also murder,  also you will honor your father and mother. All the Commandments are wrapped up in love your neighbor as yourself and love the Lord God. so Jesus's Commandments and the Ten Commandments are the same . If this thinking is correct,  you can only get to Heaven by keeping the Ten Commandments.

> Matthew 7:21-23 (summarized) Many will say to me on that day did we not prophesy in your name.  Jesus will say,  depart from me I never knew you

Jesus requires obedience to his Commandments which are the same as the Ten Commandments. So you can only get to Heaven by obeying the Ten Commandments. Jesus washed us and made us whole,  made us Kings and Priests,  but now we have to live up to that purity, which comes through obeying the Ten Commandments.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer here. Unfortunately, the question itself is an older one that is no longer on-topic for this site. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll spend some time browsing the other questions and answers here.